# How to show the document Library's content type field sinside the Word Document "Quick Parts >> document Property"

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, word

Inside our SharePoint Online document library >> I allowed the management of content type >> and i added 2 custom fields as follow:-

[image]

Now if we add the document directly from the document library as follow ( +New >> word Document):-

[image]

the document will have the related properties inside the "Quick Parts >> document Property", as follow:-

[image]

but if we upload a document from our desktop to the document library, then the "Quick Parts >> document Property" for the document will not have the custom columns .. any advice why this is happening? and can we force the custom properties to be added to the "Quick Parts >> document Property" for a document that we upload from our desktop?
Thanks

Comment: Is "Document" set as a default content type in document library (content type order = 1)?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes and it is the only content type defined inside the document library